# Posting a file using Json

Tags: javascript, json, base64, data-uri

I want to upload a binary file using json.
I choose Json because with the file I would also like to send additional information.

I am going to do this by -

1. Select  a file in the file input tag.
2. Use the HTML5 File Reader Api to read a file first.
3. Convert the file content into base64.
4. Add the base64 content to a JS object in a data uri format.
5. Convert the JS object to json and post it to the server.

I wonder if this is the only legitimate way to achieve my goal? Also, if there is a plugin already available somewhere which give me this ability?

Comment: Why don't you just use hidden input fields if you need to post additional data? It's easier to implement, since you don't need to mess with File Readers (Compatibility?), Base64 encoded data, or JSON, you can just get the values from the POST.

Comment: I need to use Ajax. A form submit will not be an elegant solution. If I am able to succeed I would convert it into a plugin. So that one can easily upload a file with additional data.

Comment: @TusharMathur: If you are insisting on using AJAX, you can still stick to established solutions (multi part form data for example), even if you will use HTML5 API. There are solutions out there that are using Flash features etc., but if you can use HTML5 instead, then it great.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the only way - one of the other ways is just to submit a form with a file in it. Such form uses `multipart/form-data` content type.

See [W3C documentation on the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2):

> The content type "`application/x-www-form-urlencode`d" is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters.
>
> **The content type "`multipart/form-data`" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.**

So, there is no need to reinvent the wheel - browsers already support sending the files along with additional information, in a simple way. You just create a form where the user can enter data and select files, then all of them are sent to the server with `multipart/form-data` content type, and your web framework should be able to understand that it deals with both files and textual data.

Comment: Please also consider the size of the data. As far as I remember, base64-encoded data takes up to 3x the size of the original file.

Comment: your solution is exactly what like the jquery plugin for ajax file upload. I see your point is valid. So is there no advantage of using json to upload a file ever? Are there no use cases?

Comment: Generally, when uploading a file, you don't want to use JSON.
You're converting binary data to plain _text_ (base64). That always takes up more space, not to mention you have to convert the file to b64 first.

Comment: @TusharMathur: There are some. Consider more complex (multi-dimensional) data, that is better represented using JSON than url-encoded forms (usually used for submitting data along with files) - in such case you could use a part encoded as JSON, but this may not be reasonable/clean enough. Also this may not give you enough advantage, if the files will be small. The other case is when you are sending something where base64-encoded data is only part of structured document (with meaningful place in the structure) - something hard to represent with `multipart/form-data`. There may be more examples.

Comment: @TusharMathur: However, I think your case is rather simple and you should probably stick to submitting flat data with files the "old school" way. You get a lot of reliability instead of questionable advantages (you do not know what you will need, so you do not know if you will need more complex solutions that will require also support on the server side).

Comment: @Cerbrus: The conversion itself is trivial. I already mentioned the size difference, but the size not always matter ;) You may need eg. to employ some more complex structure that you will be sending back & forth between different systems - in such case, you may wish to store data together, especially when the files are tiny.

Comment: @Tadeck... I'm 10 years late, but... Base64-encoded data takes 4/3x times as much space, not 3x as much. Since the Base64 'alphabet' includes 64 characters, you can encode 6 bits in each byte.